# What "get onto" means in this context?

Tags: phrasal-verbs

The following context comes from the movie "Clockwork Orange" by Stanley Kubrick

> **Tramp** Oh-hhh!!!! Go on, do me in you bastard cowards. I don't want to live anyway, not in a stinking world like this.
>
> **Alex** Oh - and what's so stinking about it?
>
> **Tramp** It's a stinking world because there's no law and order anymore. It's a stinking  world because it lets the young **get onto**
> the old like you done. It's no world for an old man anymore.

Is **get onto** the same as the phrase **get on** which means:

get on (one)

1. To bother or nag one (about something).
   *I always have to get on the kids about cleaning their rooms.
   I really wish the boss would stop getting on me about the report—I already told him I'd have it finished by the end of the week!*(source thefreedictionary)
   ?

Comment: Yes identical. British people are possibly more likely to use 'getting onto'.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey - I would use _getting on_ **at** (or _being on at_) - I find _getting on me_ strange.

Comment: @KateBunting - me too. Worth noting that Burgess (an odious creep, in my opinion) invented a lot of 'slang' usages in that novel.